# Разархивация частичных rar файлов с помощью терминала в Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, rar

Есть несколько частей одного rar архива :

Archive.part1.rar Archive.part2.rar Archive.part3.rar Archive.part4.rar

Как их разархивировать ?

Comment: В чём прикол таких вопрос-ответов? Вы  пересказываете документацию?

Comment: @0andriy, вопросо-ответы не запрещены и даже поощряемы. Если, конечно, полезны и интересны. Цитирование документации также не запрещено, т.к. почти на любой вопрос можно цитатой такой ответить. Считаю, что вопросо-ответ вполне нормален.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В терминале :
`unrar x Archive.part1.rar`

Вывод будет такого плана:

```
UNRAR 5.50 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from Archive.part1.rar

Enter password (will not be echoed) for video.mp4: 

Extracting  video.mp4                                                   27%

Extracting from Archive.part2.rar

...         video.mp4                                                   54%

Extracting from Archive.part3.rar

...         video.mp4                                                   81%

Extracting from Archive.part4.rar

...         video.mp4                                                   OK 
All OK
```